# How to collect both success and error within CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, completable-future

I want to send multiple requests in parallel to a webservice. The results should be collected by success + error, and can then be further analyzed by the caller.

```
public Map.Entry<Rsp, Errors> sendApiRequests(List<Req> reqs) {
    //will mostly remain null as errors won't occur frequently
    List<Rsp> errors = null;

    List<CompletableFuture<Rsp>> futures =
            reqs.stream()
                .map(req -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> send(req))
                        .exceptionally(ex -> {
                            //TODO this fails, because list should be final for it.
                            //but don't want to instantiate as mostly will remain just null
                            if (errors == null) errors = new ArrayList<>();
                            errors.add(req);
                        }))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //send api requests in parallel
    List<Rsp> responses = futures.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //TODO how to collect the errors? each error should also provide the underlying Req that caused the failure.
    //pending requests should not be aborted if any throwns an exception
    return new SimpleEntry(responses, errors);
}
```

Question: how can I bet collect all responses, but also collect exceptions thrown during the `send()` method?

My goal is not to return two lists: one containing all succeeded responses, and one containing errors.

Comment: You can always wrap both succeeded responses and errors into a common object and return a list of those objects. If you get the errors through exceptions, you can use [`handle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to handle both flows for each stage.

Comment: You may also want to return a `CompletableFuture` from this method too, so that it remains asynchronous as well for the caller. You could use `allOf()` on your list to do that.

Comment: Ok, but how exactly and where can I catch an collect an exception of the async process? I exception will probably be thrown on `CompletableFuture::join`? But how can I then catch the exception of only one process, but continue all the others?

Comment: If you call `join()`, the exception will indeed be thrown (wrapped in a `CompletionException`) so you could indeed surround this call with a try/catch and handle it there. It's not really clear to me what kind of result you are expecting in the end and what prevents you from processing all results.

Comment: @DidierL please see my edit to make it more clear, hopefully.

Comment: Trying to collect the errors in `.exceptionally()`, but then would like to prevent having to instantiate a collection for the errors beforehand. Because typically I won't have errors and thus creating an unneccesary list each time...

Comment: Instantiating an empty collection is negligible compared to performing the request and building the list of responses.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question I needed something similar and was able to piece together a workable solution to this from the comments above and other internet snippets which weren't quite right.

The method and `CompletableFutureCollector` classes will return a list of response or error for each request. This is implemented in Java 11, but should be adaptable for Java 8. I would recommend adapting this to pass in a `java.util.concurrent.Executor` to control the amount of parallelism. As an example you could use it like:

```
    final List<CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult<Rsp>> results =
            sendApiRequests(List.of(new Req()));
    results.stream()
            .filter(CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult::hasError)
            .map(CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult::getError)
            .forEach(error -> {
                // Do something with errors
            });
    results.stream()
            .filter(CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult::hasResult)
            .map(CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult::getResult)
            .forEach(rsp -> {
                // Do something with responses
            });
```

```
    public List<CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult<Rsp>> sendApiRequests(List<Req> reqs) {
        // The actual send implementation could be anything that you'd like to do asynchronously  
        return CompletableFutureCollector.mapAsyncAndCollectResult(reqs, req -> send(req));
    }

    // ...

    private final static class CompletableFutureCollector {
        private CompletableFutureCollector() {
        }

        public static <X, T extends CompletableFuture<X>> Collector<T, ?, CompletableFuture<List<X>>> collectResult() {
            return Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), joinResult());
        }

        private static <X, T extends CompletableFuture<X>> Function<List<T>, CompletableFuture<List<X>>> joinResult() {
            return futures -> allOf(futures)
                    .thenApply(v -> futures.stream()
                            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }

        private static <T extends CompletableFuture<?>> CompletableFuture<Void> allOf(final List<T> futures) {
            return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
        }

        public static <T, R> List<CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult<R>> mapAsyncAndCollectResult(
                final Collection<T> items, final Function<T, R> action) {
            return items.parallelStream()
                    .map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> action.apply(task)))
                    .map(CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult::handle)
                    .collect(CompletableFutureCollector.collectResult())
                    .join();
        }

        private final static class CollectorResult<R> {
            private final R result;
            private final Throwable error;

            private CollectorResult(final R result, final Throwable error) {
                this.result = result;
                this.error = error;
            }

            public boolean hasError() {
                return getError() != null;
            }

            public boolean hasResult() {
                return !hasError();
            }

            public R getResult() {
                return result;
            }

            public Throwable getError() {
                return error instanceof CompletionException ? error.getCause() : error;
            }

            public static <R> CompletableFuture<CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult<R>> handle(final CompletableFuture<R> future) {
                return future.handle(CompletableFutureCollector.CollectorResult::new);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: I haven't fully tested this solution as it was adapted from a working implementation which had some additional fast-failure cancelation logic.